# RDF Graph Reasoning Tool Suggestion

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, virtuoso, pellet

I have downloaded a large RDF graph (NT Format-contains more than millions of triples) from the web. My goal is to find interesting information from the RDF graph through reasoning. I am new with reasoning. Could you please suggest me some reasoning tools that I can easily use with my RDF graph to find interesting information? I already know about `Pellet` tool but not very clear about how to use it.

Comment: **1)** "find interesting information" - that's not the purpose of a reasoner, a reasoner *infers data* or better said, *makes implicit data explicit*. What is interesting is up to you. **2)** for RDF people usually use a triple store, especially if the dataset is very large. Reasoning approaches are rule-based. **3)** Pellet is an in-memory OWL reasoner, i.e. i) if your data isn't an OWL ontology it won't work and ii) it is very large you might get performance issues **4)** asking on StackOverflow for tools, etc. is not recommended, especially you should know this...

Comment: As AKSW said, you should find a way to cluster your data before anything else. Reasoning took a lot of CPU. Because data are generaly semantics, clustering can't be done (easly) by an automated tool.